# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 23 cannot be smaller than version 28 declared in library [com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.2.1]

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 23 cannot be smaller than version 28 declared in library [com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.2.1] C:\Users\abdullah pat\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\90ae9cef53c438f4c837bff976e4b706\transformed\car-ui-lib-2.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 23
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 23,
            or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 28,
            or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.android.car.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:143)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 23 cannot be smaller than version 28 declared in library [com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.2.1] C:\Users\abdullah pat\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\90ae9cef53c438f4c837bff976e4b706\transformed\car-ui-lib-2.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 23
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 23,
            or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 28,
            or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.android.car.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I am trying to pick an image from gallery and show it in my notes app but I get this error. I do something to resolve this error like this;

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (data != null){
            var selectedImageUrl = data.data
            if (selectedImageUrl != null){
                try {

                    context?.let {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
                            var inputStream = requireActivity().contentResolver.openInputStream(selectedImageUrl)
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                            binding.imgNote.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                            binding.imgNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            binding.layoutImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                            selectedImagePath = getPathFromUri(selectedImageUrl)!!
                        } else {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(it.contentResolver,selectedImageUrl)
                            binding.imgNote.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                            binding.imgNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            binding.layoutImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                            selectedImagePath = getPathFromUri(selectedImageUrl)!!
                        }
                    }

                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),e.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if that's exactly why but I'm checking the sdk here but I guess the application doesn't understand it. I don't want to make minSdk 28. How do I describe this control to my application or how do I solve this problem?

Here is my manifests;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.ahmetkaan.kediy">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Kediy"
            tools:targetApi="31">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

And Merged Manifest;

```
    Merging Errors: Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 23 cannot be smaller than version 28 declared in library C:\Users\abdullah pat\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\90ae9cef53c438f4c837bff976e4b706\transformed\car-ui-lib-2.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 23 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 23, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 28, or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.android.car.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures) Kediy.app main manifest (this file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly stated in your log: the library `com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib` version `2.2.1` **requires a min SDK** of 28. Emphasis on *requires*, that's not optional, this is why you are getting a **compile** error and your **runtime** if-else check cannot solve it.

Your options are also clearly communicated: you can either use an older version of the library that has a lower min SDK requirement or you can set your app's min SDK to 28, that's pretty much it.